# Comparing pointer value passed into a function by address with null resulting in reversed result

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-reference

I am well aware that there are many similar questions, but have not yet find the one that solves this. So I will also thank anyone that could point me to the duplicate.

Say I have a function that takes a void pointer and modify the value inside:

```
int func(void *head)
{
    if (head == NULL){
        printf("is null\n");
        /* do sth with the value */
    }
    else{
        printf("not null\n");
        /* do sth with the value */
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And I passed a `NULL` pointer by address into it:

```
void *setList = NULL;

func(&setList);
```

It would give me `not null`, which is not what I want. (if passing by value it works well)

What was I missing? How could I judge if it's a `NULL` pointer when passed by address?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `func (setList);` -- you are not passing `NULL`, you are passing the address of the pointer....(which is never `NULL`) Your compiler should be WARNING you about passing an *Incompatible Pointer Type*.

Comment: @David C. Rankin There's no warning. Any pointer (incl a `void**`) can be passed to a `void*`. (But yeah, you'd get a warning if `void` was anything else.)

Comment: @ikegami -- ooh, right you are. Strike the warning part of the comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this declaration

```
void *setList = NULL;
```

you declared the variable `setList` that occupies a memory. So the address of the variable itself is not equal to `NULL`. It is the value of the variable that is stored in the allocated for the variable memory that is equal to `NULL`.

In this call

```
func(&setList);
```

the type of the argument expression is `void **`.

Within the function declared like

```
int func(void *head);
```

you have at first cast the pointer `head` to the type `void **`.

For example

```
void **p = ( void ** )head;
```

and then in the if statement you need to dereference the pointer `p` like

```
if ( *p == NULL )
//...
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func( void *head )
{
    void **p = ( void ** )head;
    
    if ( *p == NULL )
    {
        puts( "p is a null pointer" );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "p is not a null pointer" );
    }
    
    return 1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    void *setList = NULL;
    
    func( &setList );
    
    int x = 10;
    
    setList = &x;
    
    func( &setList );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
p is a null pointer
p is not a null pointer
```

As for your original code then a question arises why is not the function declared like

```
int func(void **head);
```

if you are going to pass a pointer to pointer?

Answer (score 1):

```
void *setList = NULL;
```

you create the variable `setlist` having the type of `pointer to void` and initialize it to NULL.

```
func(&setList);
```

you pass the address of the variable `setList` not the value of it. The variable is the valid object and its address is by definition not NULL.